# Error in recording audio using mp3DirectCut

Tags: audio, audio-recording

I am trying to record an audio being played by a media player. I prefer to use mp3DirectCut over Audacity to preserve much of the sound quality as possible. But whenever I press the record button, I always get an error message:

```
Could not open wave/audio device
```

Screenshot:

[image: mp3DirectCut recording error]

How can I get the recording to work?

EDIT: Here are other screenshots:

[image: Settings 1]
[image: Settings 2]

Comment: What "wave/audio device" have you selected in the program?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean, but under Settings>Configuration>Devices>Input devices it shows "No input devices". Should I enable the recorder in the Control Panel?

Comment: Well you'll definitely need to be able to select an input device. If you don't see one, something is wrong. What does it show for recording devices in 'sound' under control panel?

Comment: @Appleoddity It shows Microphone. I enabled the device and set the recording Volume to 50, and yet mp3DirectCut does not record any sound being played through the computer.

Comment: The Microphone device will not pick up sound from your PC unless you have a microphones plugged in and sitting next to your speakers. I'm trying to recall what the proper method is here. But basically, you need to choose a different input device and adjust your recording levels so that the PC's output is recorded and not something like a "microphone." It's all done in the "sound" control panel app.

Comment: Unfortunately, disabling the Microphone causes that "Could not open wave/audio device" error. In Audacity, recording works just fine. I could not find any solution in the web to get this program to record.

Comment: What other devices are listed besides microphone in control panel?

Comment: Is shows only another "Microphone" (so there are two "Microphones").